# how to store seleced checkbox values in array list in android

Tags: android, arraylist, checkbox

I have created simple quiz app. In that I want to get true value of `checkbox`. there are three `checkbox` questions. Now how to get right value of selected checkbox using `ArrayList`. So when multiple answers are selected by the user I need to store them in an `arraylist` and need to compare the selected answers with that in database. In my code I am storing the selected value id's one by one but at a time it is storing only one value. How to store all the selected `checkbox` id's in my `arraylist`?

My code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.pujadudhat.quizapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_que1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/que_1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_que1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="questionOne"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="questionOne"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="questionOne"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_que2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/que_2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_que2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt1_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="questionTwo"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt1_2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt2_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="questionTwo"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt2_2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt3_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="questionTwo"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt3_2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_que3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/que_3" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_que3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt1_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="questionThree"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt1_3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt2_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="questionThree"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt2_3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_opt3_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="questionThree"
            android:text="@string/rb_opt3_3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_que4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/que_4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_prime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionFour"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt1_4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_prime2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionFour"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt2_4" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_prime3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionFour"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt3_4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_que5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/que_5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_composite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionFive"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt1_5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_composite2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionFive"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt2_5" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_composite3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionFive"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt3_5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_que6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/que_6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_multiple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionSix"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt1_6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_multiple2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionSix"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt2_6" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_multiple3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="questionSix"
        android:text="@string/cb_opt3_6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/que_7" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rolex_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="calsulateScore"
            android:text="@string/btn_text" />



        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="resetScore"
            android:text="@string/btn_reset" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.pujadudhat.quizapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int myScore = 0;
boolean que1;
boolean que2;
boolean que3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * Get Answer for que. #1
 */

public void questionOne(View view) {

    RadioButton opt1RadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_opt1);
    que1 = opt1RadioButton.isChecked();

    if (opt1RadioButton.isChecked()) {

        myScore = myScore + 1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void questionTwo(View view){
    RadioButton opt2RadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_opt2_2);
    que2 = opt2RadioButton.isChecked();

    if(opt2RadioButton.isChecked()){

        myScore = myScore + 1;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void questionThree(View view){
    RadioButton opt2RadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_opt2_3);
    que3 = opt2RadioButton.isChecked();

    if(opt2RadioButton.isChecked()){

        myScore = myScore + 1;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Thank You

Comment: why dont u use radio button, only one button is selected at a time and easy for you u to check if its correct answer or not

Comment: first do all thing dynamically in layout you added for 3 question. Use view pager or recycle view and through position you can manage all things

Comment: I am already done with logic of radio button. Now for checkbox I need to declare every checkbox with id so rather than doing that I want to store reference in array list and retrieve it. How to do that??

Comment: I am beginner. I just want to store values in Arraylist and retrieve. that's all the requirement of project

Comment: ok if there is 100 or 1k questions then this will work?

Comment: I don't know. I am beginner. You say. What's the best solution

Comment: what is the best way to get selected value of checkbox ??

Comment: 1)create custom object question list or array  2) create view and inflate that as per position 3) on next prev button ++ or -- position ....

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create Custom classes,

```
public class Answer{
private int questionNumber;
private boolean answer;
    public Answer(int questionNumber,boolean answer)
    {
         this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
         this,.answer=answer
    }
    public void setQuestionNumber(int questionNumber){this.questionNumber=questionNumber;}
    public void setAnswer(boolean answer){this.answer=answer;}

    public int getQuestionNumber(){return this.questionNumber;}
    public boolean getAnswer(){return this.answer;}

}
```

and apply to your mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Answer _answer;
    private List<Answer> _listAnswer = new ArrayList<>();

public void questionOne(View view) {

    RadioButton opt1RadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_opt1);
    que1 = opt1RadioButton.isChecked();

    if (opt1RadioButton.isChecked()) {

        _answer = new Answer(1,true);
        myScore = myScore + 1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        _answer = new Answer(1,false);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
//to store the answer into list
    _listAnswer.add(_answer);
}
```

do the rest for question 2,3... total question you have

and for access the list you can try :

```
for(int i=0;i<_listAnswer.size();i++)
{
     String answerValue = if(_listAnswer.get(i).getAnswer()) ? "Right" : "Wrong"

     if(_listAnswer.get(i).getAnswer()){ myScore++; }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Question Number : " + _listAnswer.get(i).getQuestionNumber() + " is " + answerValue);
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: Let me try and run. Thanks

Comment: you can remove myScore+=1 in every question class and just put them into the Looping for, it's more easy to track. I just edit my answer.